# Script Lab, no finish load

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

It does not finish loading and does not give error either. Nothing works in the add-on, no code, no execution, no function, no tutorial or anything... it just stays charging. The problem happens on excel desktop, on web it doesn't happen. The error started when I changed versions, I don't remember which one I was in and switched to production. Apparently the solution can be simple, from restarting the add-on, or its complete uninstallation. However this becomes impossible, and I cannot correct the error. Thank.
#office-js #scriptlab

Try to uninstall and install the add-on, thus restarting its functions, although that implies losing the codes that were not uploaded to github, however it is impossible to perform. I have no knowledge of programming to know what kind of error it is.

Comment: The codes may exist in "My Snippets" on one computer.